# Give role in specific message sent

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I want to give a role for sending specific number of message

Like if they manage to send **1k messages** they will get a specific role

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: Please improve the question and show some of your approach. Cuz it'll need a Database, a message collector and a role giving system. So it'll take a whole project which is not what StackOverFlow is for.

Comment: Oh I already have this all just need to know how to give it the role when seeing it send 1k message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you know the role id then

```js
roleID = "100000000000000001";
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
if(memberHasEnoughMessage && !member.roles.get(roleID)){
    let role = Guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
    if(member && role){
        member.roles.add(role);
    }
}
```

if you don't know the role id and only know the name then

```js
const role = Guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === '10k message');
```

If you want to create a new role (let's say with permission to ping everyone) then

```js
Guild.createRole( {name:"10k", color: "#f6f61", permissions:["MENTION_EVERYONE"] } );
```

So the final code should be like

```js
roleID = "100000000000000001";
let member = message.mentions.members.first();
if(memberHasEnoughMessage){
/*
    If you already know the role ID
    let role = Guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
*/
    let role = Guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
    ler role = Guild.roles.cache.find(r=> r.name === '1k');
    if(!role){
        await Guild.createRole( {name:"Mentioners", color: "#ff0000", permissions:["MENTION_EVERYONE"] } ).then( (newRole) =>
            role = rnewRole;
        }).catch(console.log);
    }
    if(member && role){
        member.roles.add(role);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure to comprehend? Where is the 1000 message needed line code?

Comment: @Oofin You said in the comment that you have that figured out and only need the function to react. You said `Oh I already have this all just need to know how to give it the role when seeing it send 1k message`

Comment: Sorry for my late respond. I found out how. Thanks!